# Add field to display in views using a custom table

Tags: views, 8

I joined a custom table in an existing Views (using hook_views_query_alter) and now I'd like to display fields from this table.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For your custom table you need to add custom field handler for views.
Check out below link for example code.

https://gist.github.com/juampynr/5816530

Hope this will help.